# Deno server TLS Alert HandshakeFailure

Tags: fetch, tls1.2, deno

I just installed deno to try use it. I wanted to use [**fetch**](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#fetch) function to post some data like this :

```js
async function post(url: string, data: FormData): Promise<Response> {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
  });
  return response;
}
```

I get this error when I run my code with `deno run --allow-net main.ts`:

```
TLS alert received: Message {
    typ: Alert,
    version: TLSv1_2,
    payload: Alert(
        AlertMessagePayload {
            level: Fatal,
            description: HandshakeFailure,
        },
    ),
}
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: error sending request for url (https://***********): error trying to connect: received fatal alert: HandshakeFailure
    at handleError (deno:core/core.js:186:12)
    at jsonOpParseResult (deno:core/core.js:356:9)
    at asyncHandle (deno:core/core.js:223:40)
    at Array.asyncHandlers.<computed> (deno:core/core.js:238:9)
    at handleAsyncMsgFromRust (deno:core/core.js:207:32)
```

However, when I use Curl in Command-line to send data instead, it works.

`deno --version` gives me:

```
deno 1.8.3 (release, x86_64-apple-darwin)
v8 9.0.257.3
typescript 4.2.2
```

Why does it work with Curl but not with deno ?  How can I fix this problem

Comment: Needed more details. about URL, to reproduce error,

Comment: I'm sure its something with the TLS version or the certs. I've had this error with the url `https://bet.szerencsejatek.hu/` while `https://szerencsejatek.hu/` (another server of same company) works fine.
My workaround was simply to use curl in `Deno.run`

Answer (score 0):

You have probably run into [this issue](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6427)

Basically the TLS library that Deno uses ([rustls](https://github.com/rustls/rustls)) is quite strict and does not support weak ciphers. You can check what ciphers the server offers using the [Qualsys SSL Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/).